# Função de converter números decimais para extenso usando VBA em Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Estou com uma função, =SpellNumber(), que ao colocar um número lá, ela solta o número por extenso. Agr, ela solta, na parte dos centavos, and X Cents. Gostaria que ela soltasse with X/100. Alguém sabe como eu altero o código pra ela fazer isso? Aprecio a ajuda e segue o código abaixo:

```
Option Explicit
'Main Function
Function SpellNumber(ByVal MyNumber)
    Dim Dollars, Cents, Temp
    Dim DecimalPlace, Count
    ReDim Place(9) As String
    Place(2) = " Thousand "
    Place(3) = " Million "
    Place(4) = " Billion "
    Place(5) = " Trillion "
    ' String representation of amount.
     MyNumber = Trim(Str(MyNumber))
    ' Position of decimal place 0 if none.
    DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")
    ' Convert cents and set MyNumber to dollar amount.
    If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
        Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & _
                  "00", 2))
        MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))
    End If
     Count = 1
    Do While MyNumber <> ""
         Temp = GetHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))
        If Temp <> "" Then Dollars = Temp & Place(Count) & Dollars
        If Len(MyNumber) > 3 Then
            MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)
        Else
             MyNumber = ""
         End If
        Count = Count + 1
    Loop
    Select Case Dollars
    Case ""
        Dollars = "No Dollars"
    Case "One"
        Dollars = "One Dollar"
     Case Else
        Dollars = Dollars & " Dollars"
End Select
Select Case Cents
    Case ""
        Cents = " and No Cents"
    Case "One"
        Cents = " and One Cent"
          Case Else
        Cents = " and " & Cents & " Cents"
End Select
SpellNumber = Dollars & Cents
End Function

' Converts a number from 100-999 into text 
Function GetHundreds(ByVal MyNumber)
    Dim Result As String
    If Val(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function
    MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)
    ' Convert the hundreds place.
    If Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1) <> "0" Then
         Result = GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1)) & " Hundred "
    End If
    ' Convert the tens and ones place.
     If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
        Result = Result & GetTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))
Else
    Result = Result & GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
End If
GetHundreds = Result
End Function

' Converts a number from 10 to 99 into text. 
Function GetTens(TensText)
    Dim Result As String
    Result = ""           ' Null out the temporary function value.
    If Val(Left(TensText, 1)) = 1 Then   ' If value between 10-19...
        Select Case Val(TensText)
            Case 10: Result = "Ten"
            Case 11: Result = "Eleven"
            Case 12: Result = "Twelve"
            Case 13: Result = "Thirteen"
            Case 14: Result = "Fourteen"
            Case 15: Result = "Fifteen"
            Case 16: Result = "Sixteen"
            Case 17: Result = "Seventeen"
            Case 18: Result = "Eighteen"
            Case 19: Result = "Nineteen"
            Case Else
        End Select
    Else                                 ' If value between 20-99...
        Select Case Val(Left(TensText, 1))
            Case 2: Result = "Twenty "
            Case 3: Result = "Thirty "
            Case 4: Result = "Forty "
            Case 5: Result = "Fifty "
            Case 6: Result = "Sixty "
            Case 7: Result = "Seventy "
            Case 8: Result = "Eighty "
            Case 9: Result = "Ninety "
            Case Else
        End Select
        Result = Result & GetDigit _
            (Right(TensText, 1))  ' Retrieve ones place.
    End If
    GetTens = Result
End Function

' Converts a number from 1 to 9 into text. 
Function GetDigit(Digit)
    Select Case Val(Digit)
        Case 1: GetDigit = "One"
        Case 2: GetDigit = "Two"
        Case 3: GetDigit = "Three"
        Case 4: GetDigit = "Four"
        Case 5: GetDigit = "Five"
        Case 6: GetDigit = "Six"
        Case 7: GetDigit = "Seven"
        Case 8: GetDigit = "Eight"
        Case 9: GetDigit = "Nine"
        Case Else: GetDigit = ""
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Dê um exemplo correcto de valor numérico mas valor por extenso.

Comment: Se eu escrevo: "=SpellNumber(123.45)", sai: "One Hundred Twenty Three Dollars and Forty Five Cents"

Comment: Agora escreva por extenso a forma como pretende ler o número

Comment: Gostaria que saisse: "One Hundred Twenty Three with x/100", sem o "Dollars"e sem o "Cents", sendo X o número de centavos.

Comment: Vou verificar as alterações necessárias

Comment: Obrigado, Jorge!

Comment: @J.Doe Favor editar a pergunta com estes dados e alterar o título para um mais compreensível. Do que pretende realizar, por exemplo: `Função de converter números decimais para extenso`

Comment: @J.Doe por favor verifique e considere-a certa se responder correctamente à sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Apenas a função *SpellNumber*  alterada, quando não tem casas decimais apenas apresenta a parte inteira.

Comentei o código antigo relativo aos cêntimos.

```
Function SpellNumber(ByVal MyNumber)
    Dim Dollars, Temp
    Dim Decimals, Count 'DecimalPlace,

    ReDim Place(9) As String
    Place(2) = " Thousand "
    Place(3) = " Million "
    Place(4) = " Billion "
    Place(5) = " Trillion "


    Decimals = (MyNumber * 100 Mod 100)

    If Decimals <> 0 Then
        Decimals = " with " & Decimals & "/100"
    Else
        Decimals = ""
    End If


    ' String representation of amount.
     MyNumber = Trim(Str(MyNumber))

    ' Position of decimal place 0 if none.
    'DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")
    ' Convert cents and set MyNumber to dollar amount.
    'If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
    '    Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & _
    '              "00", 2))
    '    MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))
    'End If

    Count = 1
    Do While MyNumber <> ""
         Temp = GetHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))
        If Temp <> "" Then Dollars = Temp & Place(Count) & Dollars
        If Len(MyNumber) > 3 Then
            MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)
        Else
             MyNumber = ""
         End If
        Count = Count + 1
    Loop
    Select Case Dollars
    Case ""
        Dollars = "No Dollars"
    Case "One"
        Dollars = "One Dollar"
     Case Else
        Dollars = Dollars & " Dollars"
End Select



'Select Case Cents
'    Case ""
'        Cents = " and No Cents"
'    Case "One"
'        Cents = " and One Cent"
'          Case Else
'        Cents = " and " & Cents & " Cents"
'End Select


'SpellNumber = Dollars & Cents

SpellNumber = Dollars & Decimals
End Function
```